# Probability Proof $ \mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3}\right) = ... $

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

How would I go about proving this statement:
$\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3}\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{3} \mathbb{P}\left(A_{i}\right)\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2}\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{3}\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{2} \cap A_{3}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap A_{3}\right)$

The probability space is $(\Omega,\mathbb{P})$
and for the upper equation applies $A_{i} \subseteq \Omega, i=1,2,3$

My idea is to reshape the LHS:

So we have

(i)
$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{3} \mathbb{P}\left(A_{i}\right)\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2}\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{3}\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{2} \cap A_{3}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap A_{3}\right)$

with

(ii) $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{3} \mathbb{P}\left(A_{i}\right)\right) = \mathbb{P}(A_{1}) \cup \mathbb{P}(A_{2}) \cup \mathbb{P}(A_{3}) $

(iii) $ \mathbb{P}(A_{1}) = \mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \setminus A_{2}\right)  + \mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2}\right)   <=> 
-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \setminus A_{2}\right) - \mathbb{P}(A_{1})$

same for $\mathbb{P}(A_{2})$ and  $\mathbb{P}(A_{3})$

Now we combine (i), (ii) and we get:

(iV)
$\mathbb{P}(A_{1}) \cup \mathbb{P}(A_{2}) \cup \mathbb{P}(A_{3})-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2}\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{3}\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{2} \cap A_{3}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap A_{3}\right)$

Now we combine (iV), (iii) and we get:

(V)
$\mathbb{P}(A_{1}) \cup \mathbb{P}(A_{2}) \cup \mathbb{P}(A_{3})+
\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \setminus A_{2}\right) - \mathbb{P}(A_{1})+
\mathbb{P}\left(A_{3} \setminus A_{1}\right) - \mathbb{P}(A_{3})+
\mathbb{P}\left(A_{2} \setminus A_{3}\right) - \mathbb{P}(A_{2})+\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap A_{3}\right) = 
\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \setminus A_{2}\right) +
\mathbb{P}\left(A_{3} \setminus A_{1}\right) +
\mathbb{P}\left(A_{2} \setminus A_{3}\right) +\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap A_{3}\right)$

Now we use this equation:

(Vi)
$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A \backslash B)+\mathbb{P}(B \backslash A)+\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$

And finally we use (VI) on (V)

$\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \setminus A_{2}\right) +
\mathbb{P}\left(A_{3} \setminus A_{1}\right) +
\mathbb{P}\left(A_{2} \setminus A_{3}\right) +\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap A_{3}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3}\right)$

Could this work?
If yes i will get drunk today :)

Comment: Is $\mathbb P$ the probability measure function? How can you put the union sign for a number?

Comment: I think this works (I didn't check any of the details but the idea seems fine) but it's way more complicated than necessary. You ought to use the inclusion-exclusion principle, namely that $\mathbb{P}(X \cup Y) = \mathbb{P}(X) + \mathbb{P}(Y) - \mathbb{P}(X \cap Y)$. For your problem, define $B = A_1 \cup A_2$. Then $\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) = \mathbb{P}(B \cup A_3) = \mathbb{P}(B) + \mathbb{P}(A_3) - \mathbb{P}(B \cap A_3)$. Use inclusion-exclusion again to rewrite $\mathbb{P}(B)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B \cap A_3)$ in terms of the $\mathbb{P}(A_i)$'s.

Comment: @ Fareed AF Yes $\mathbb{P}$ stands for the probability measure function.  Because of my bad English, i do not understand the second question :)

Comment: @  diracdeltafunk Well, I've never heard of it but thanks for the tip, i try to use it :)

Comment: This is the "inclusion-exclusion principle" for three sets. In fact, there is a general version for $n$ sets, see here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427473/inclusion-exclusion-probability-proof-using-a-partition-of-the-space.

Comment: @SK19 Mmh could be, but I think my problem is a little bit different ?

Comment: Have you looked at the first answer? I found the explanation for three events quite sufficient.

Comment: @germinator, I can't see how your problem is different from what SK19 posted.

At any rate, I would recommend first proving a special case: that
$$
\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cup A_2) = \mathbb{P}(A_1) + \mathbb{P}(A_2)  - \mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2).
$$
And even before this, how about first proving the first equality in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle).  In general, **all the terms that are subtracted are intended to correct for an "overcount"**.

Comment: @SK19 Yes i saw it. Sry, my math skills aren't good, I'm still in school 11 grade (Germany). 

My intention is only to find out if my way works

Comment: You may add the proof-verification tag.

Comment: @SK19 done:) and sry for the problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this identity is the probabilistic version of the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) in the special case of three sets.

Your calculation looks good to me. I'd consider proof by diagram rigorous in this setting. For example, one can read off your equation (V), namely,
$$\Bbb P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) = \color{#ff0000}{\Bbb P(A_2 \setminus A_3)} + \color{#009f00}{\Bbb P(A_3 \setminus A_1)} + \color{#3f7fff}{\Bbb P(A_1 \setminus A_2)} + \color{#7f00ff}{\Bbb P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)} ,$$
directly from the below Venn diagram, appropriately labeled.

[image]

Comment: "Your calculation looks good to me"  This is exactly what I wanted to hear :)
I will study Inclusion-Exclusion Principle could be helpful for future problems. To solve this problem on my way has taken me way to long.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help! Another, less symmetric way of proving this is applying the two-set Inclusion-Exclusion Principle twice. A good exercise for checking that you understand that principle well is to prove the $n$-set version by induction.