# $\mathbb{P}(B_1) = S_1-2S_2+3S_3-4S_4+...+(-1)^{n-1}n S_n$

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ be events in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$,
\begin{aligned}
S_0 &= 1, \\
S_1 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_i), \\
S_2 &= \sum_{1 \leq k_1 < k_2 \leq n} \mathbb{P}(A_{k_1} \cap A_{k_2}),\\
\dots \\
S_r &= \sum_{\mathcal{J}_r}\mathbb{P}(A_{k_1} \cap A_{k_2} \cap \dots \cap A_{k_r}),
\end{aligned}
where the sum is taken over the unordered subsets $\mathcal{J}_r=[k_1,k_2,\dots,k_r]$ of $\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$. Let $B_m$, $m \geq 0$, be the event in which exactly $m$ events from $A_1,A_2, \dots, A_n$ occur. Then

1. $\mathbb{P}(B_0) = 1-S_1+S_2-S_3+...+(-1)^n S_n$
2. $\mathbb{P}(B_1) = S_1-2S_2+3S_3-4S_4+...+(-1)^{n-1}n S_n$

I believe these results should follow from inclusion-exclusion principle. For the first part the proof that I found is for sets, not probabilities (https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/111104026/lecture17.pdf). There is one question on mathstack ([Inclusion Exclusion Probability Proof Using a Partition of the Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427473/inclusion-exclusion-probability-proof-using-a-partition-of-the-space)) where someone answered by working with sets, but not probabilities. Not sure how the proofs should look like in this case.

I couldn't find proofs for these equations anywhere so maybe there's someone who might have some sources where I could find the proofs? Some help of proving them ourselves would be appreciated as well.

Comment: This exercise is taken from Shiryaev 'Probability' book, it asks to prove a general $\mathbb{P_m}=\sum_{r=m}^n (-1)^{r-m}C_r^m S_r$. Cannot find its proof as well haha.

Comment: Years ago, I uploaded a proof using the generating functions and binomial theorem. http://www.csun.edu/~sungjin/SJK_IncExc.pdf

Comment: Nice. Just to comment that the formula $\enspace\displaystyle-{\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}}(-1)^{p-r}\binom pr=(-1)^{m+p}\binom{p-1}{m-1}\enspace$ I used in my answer is Lemma 1 in @SungjinKim's pdf.

Answer (score 1):

For $[k]\in\mathcal I_m$, let $A([k]):=A_{k_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{k_m}$. Then
by the inclusion-exclusion principle:\begin{align*}\mathbb P(B_m)+\cdots+\mathbb P(B_n)&=\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcup_{[k]\in\mathcal I_m}A([k])\right)\\[.4em]&=\sum_{\emptyset\subsetneq J\subseteq\mathcal I_m}(-1)^{|J|+1}\,\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcap_{[k]\in J}A([k])\right)\\[.4em]&=\sum_{\emptyset\subsetneq J\subseteq\mathcal I_m}(-1)^{|J|+1}\,\mathbb P\!\left(A\Biggl(\bigcup_{[k]\in J}[k]\Biggr)\!\right)\\[.4em]&=\sum_{p=m}^n\sum_{[\ell]\in\mathcal I_p}\left[\sum_{\substack{\emptyset\subsetneq J\subseteq\mathcal I_m\\\bigcup_{[k]\in J}[k]=[\ell]}}(-1)^{|J|+1}\right]\mathbb P\bigl(A([\ell])\bigr).\end{align*}
By relabelling, the sum between brackets depends only on $m$ and $p$ (not on $[\ell]$) and equals (again by the inclusion-exclusion principle):
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{\emptyset\subsetneq J\subseteq\mathcal I_m\\\bigcup_{[k]\in J}[k]=[\ell]}}(-1)^{|J|+1}
&=-{\sum_{K\subseteq[\ell]}(-1)^{|K|}\sum_{\substack{\emptyset\subsetneq J\subseteq\mathcal I_m\\\bigcup_{[k]\in J}[k]\subseteq[\ell]\setminus K}}}(-1)^{|J|}\\[.4em]
&=-{\sum_{K\subseteq[\ell]}}(-1)^{|K|}\left[(1-1)^{\binom{p-|K|}m}-1\right]\\
&=(1-1)^p-\sum_{r=p-m+1}^p(-1)^r\sum_{\substack{K\subseteq[\ell]\\|K|=r}}1\\
&=0^p-\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}(-1)^{p-r}\binom pr\\[.4em]
&=0^p+(-1)^{m+p}\binom{p-1}{m-1}.
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(B_m)+\cdots+\mathbb P(B_n)&=\sum_{p=m}^n\left[0^p+(-1)^{m+p}\binom{p-1}{m-1}\right]\sum_{\ell\in\mathcal I_p}\mathbb P\bigl(A([\ell])\bigr)\notag\\[.4em]&=\sum_{p=m}^n\left[0^p+(-1)^{m+p}\binom{p-1}{m-1}\right]S_p.\tag{$E_m$}\end{align}
We finally get $\mathbb P(B_m)$ with $(E_m)-(E_{m+1})$:
\begin{align*}\mathbb P(B_m)&=\left(0^m+\binom{m-1}{m-1}\right)S_m+\sum_{p=m+1}^n(-1)^{m+p}\left[\binom{p-1}{m-1}+\binom{p-1}m\right]S_p\\[.4em]&=S_m+\sum_{p=m+1}^n(-1)^{m+p}\binom pmS_p\\[.4em]&=\sum_{p=m}^n(-1)^{m+p}\binom pmS_p.\end{align*}